# Unit testing view model that uses SelectMany to call an async method in ReactiveUI

Tags: unit-testing, tdd, system.reactive, reactiveui

I am new to ReactiveUI and trying to test a view model that looks like this:

```
public interface IService
{
    Task<SessionModel> GetData(string id);
}

/// Provides a group of schedulers available to be used
public interface ISchedulers
{
    IScheduler Default { get; }
    IScheduler Dispatcher { get; }
}

public class MyVm : ReactiveObject
{
    IService service;

    public MyVm(ISchedulers schedulers, IService service)
    {
        this.service = service;
        this.session = this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.SessionId)
                           .SelectMany(SearchSession)
                           .ObserveOn(schedulers.Default)
                           .ToProperty(this, x => x.Session);
    }

    private async Task<SessionModel> SearchSession(string id)
    {
        return await this.service.GetData(id);
    }

    private string sessionId;
    public string SessionId
    {
        get => sessionId;
        set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref sessionId, value);
    }


    readonly ObservableAsPropertyHelper<SessionModel> session;
    public SessionModel Session
    {
        get { return session.Value; }
    }

}

public class SessionModel { }
```

I'm mocking the service call to return dummy data, but not sure what I need to do with a `TestScheduler` in order to get the `SelectMany` to work.

Here's a test class that shows how i would create a test for the view model.  The goal is to eventually be able to check that the model got set:

```
[TestClass]
public class MyVmTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void CreateClass
    {
       var subject = new MyVm(/*pass in mocks*/);

       subject.SessionId="test";

       Assert.IsNotNull(subject.Session);
     }
}
```

Comment: What's `ISchedulers`?

Comment: it provides the list of possible schedulers for an observable to use.  It's mocked in the test to return a `TestScheduler`.  in the real code it returns `System.Reactive.Concurrency.Scheduler.Default`.

Comment: I updated your code, with things I assume you have. Can you add what you're trying to test?

Comment: added test class.

Comment: i can't seem to add more code without adding more words.  Just note that SessionId would be properly defined to use `RaiseAndSetIfChanged`

Comment: Yeah, just realized that's off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think using `TestScheduler` is necessary. The following passes for me (using `Moq`):

```
var mockSchedulers = new Mock<ISchedulers>();
mockSchedulers.Setup(s => s.Default).Returns(Scheduler.Immediate);
var id = "123";
var mockService = new Mock<IService>();
var returnSession = new SessionModel();
mockService.Setup(s => s.GetData(It.Is<string>(i => i == id)))
    .ReturnsAsync(returnSession);
var target = new MyVm(mockSchedulers.Object, mockService.Object);

target.SessionId = id;

Assert.IsNotNull(target.Session);
Assert.AreEqual(returnSession, target.Session);
```

`TestScheduler` is best when you're trying to test something with time (like a Delay, proving that the Delay actually happened). You're not really doing that here.

Comment: Hmm, the problem is that i have a class that implements `ISchedulers` and makes all the properties return `TestScheduler`.  So, if i have to have a different mock of `IScheduler` for each test so that i can flip between `Default.Immediate` or the `TestScheduler`, how would you suggest I implement `vm.Session` so that in other tests i can set a value for it?

Comment: Never mind.  made it work by using `TestScheduler` and calling `Start()` after setting the id.  Thanks!!